# No CurrentSessionContext configured, while using getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am changing my code from `openSession()` to `getCurrentSession()` so it won't create connections at each request.
I have done code in class as:

```
    public Session openSession(boolean current1){
        int count = 0;
        int MAX_COUNT = 10;
//      this.printIdMap();
        while( count++ < MAX_COUNT) {
            try {
                this.session = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                this.transaction = this.session.beginTransaction();
                
                this.IncDecCounter(true);
//              this.session.getTransaction().commit();
                break;
            }
            catch ( Exception e ) {
                this.printIdMap();
                e.printStackTrace();
                try { this.session.close(); } catch( Exception e1 ) {}
            }
        }
        return this.session;
    }
```

I have checked in multiple places to set property in hibernate.cfg.xml file.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

I also tried

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocal‌​SessionContext</property>
```

but facing error as

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

The hibernate version which I am using is 5.4.1

Comment: You have to display your code in your question.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I have displayed my method where I am going to use getCurrentSession().

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine your `Hibernate`  session manager class looks like this

```html
public class HibernateSessionManager {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryBuilder
                .buildServiceRegistry());
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Use this property in your configuration file

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Instead of you currecnt one i.e

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocal‌​SessionContext</property>
```

And get your session with

```
Session session = HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Comment: openSession() is already implemented and working fine. But I am assigned to switch it to getCurrentSession().

Comment: @AlyanAhmed then please share your session manager source code to investigate your implementation

Comment: I edited my question and placed my code there.